# Wanted: a very simple Java RegExp API

Tags: java, regex

I'm tired of writing

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(...
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
   ...
```

Over and over again in my code. I was going to write a helper class to make it neater, but I then I wondered: is there a library that tries to provide a simpler facade for Regular Expressions in Java?

I'm thinking something in the style of [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) and [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

**CLARIFICATION**: I am actually hoping for some general library that would make working with regular expression a more streamlined experience, kind of like how perl does it. The code above was just an example.

I was thinking of something I could use like this:

```
for (int question : RegEx.findAllInts("SO question #(\\d+)", str)) {
   // do something with int
}
```

Again, this is just an example of one of the many things I'd like to have. Probably not even a good example. APIs are hard.

**UPDATE**: I guess the answer is "No". Thanks for all the answers, have an upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just write your own wrapper method? Sure, you should not reinvent the wheel but another library also means another dependency.

Comment: Same reason I like `StringUtils.isBlank` over my own implementation. When people implement reinvent the wheel, they tend to do it in subtly incompatible ways.

Comment: Accepted since it seems this is my only option.

Answer (score 2):

`Pattern` should only be compiled once; save it in a static final field. This at least saves you from repeating, at coding time an runtime, this step. That is to say, this step ought not always go hand-in-hand with creating a `Matcher` for performance reasons.

In your example, it seems `RegEx` plays the role of a `Matcher` object anyway. I hope it's not supposed to be a class with a static method since this would not work in a multithreaded environment -- the `find` and `getInt` calls are not connected then. So you need a `Matcher` of some sort anyway.

And so you're back to precisely the Java API, when design considerations are factored in. No I don't think there's a shorter way to do this *correctly and efficiently*.

Comment: I changed my example to something that might be less offensive. Most of the time I don't care about efficiency. *Readability* is much more important. If you can use ThreadLocal and some more magic to make my simple code simple, I think it is worth it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a java library which has extend feature over the built-in java regex library . Have a look at [RegExPlus](http://codesaway.info/RegExPlus/). I haven't tried it personally.But hope this helps.

Comment: We're getting closer... That looks very interesting, even if not quite the direction I was looking for.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't do anything about streamlining the API, but very interesting in its own right.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it's always bugged me, too, having to write so much boilerplate to perform such common tasks.  I think it would help a lot if String had a pair of methods like

```
public String findFirst(String regex)

public String[] findAll(String regex)
```

These represent the two most commonly performed regex operations that aren't already supported by String methods.  If we had those, plus a dynamic replacement facility like [`Rewriter`](http://elliotth.blogspot.com/2004/07/java-implementation-of-rubys-gsub.html), we could almost forget about Pattern and Matcher.  We would only need them when we're writing something really complicated, like a `findAllInts()` method. :D

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 1.4, you can also use [String.matches(String regex)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)). Which precisely is a facade to the aforementionned code.

Comment: It does *not* do the same thing. It replaces the `find()` call with a `matches()` call. Of course that makes sense, if you look at the name, but it's a quite different operation.

Comment: Not quite. `String.matches(regex)` is a short-cut for `Pattern.matches(regex, someString)`, not for `Matcher.find()`.

Comment: `find()` finds a substring in a String. `matches(...)` matches an entire input String: not the same thing! The API docs you linked to specifically says so: *"An invocation of this method of the form str.matches(regex) yields exactly the same result as the expression `Pattern.matches(regex,  str)`"*

Answer (score 1):

There is [Jakarta Regexp](http://jakarta.apache.org/regexp/index.html) (see the [`RE`](http://jakarta.apache.org/regexp/apidocs/org/apache/regexp/RE.html) class). Have a look at [this old thread](http://marc.info/?l=jakarta-regexp-user&m=107092899302669&w=2) for advantages of Jakarta's RegExp package over the Java built-in RegEx.

Comment: Although Apache's RE are rather limited: no look arounds, for example.

Comment: @Bart Agreed, it's not very advanced but at the end, it really depends on the needs of the OP.

Comment: There are no advantages to using Jakarta Regexp that I can see.  It's still severely lacking in features, and the API is only slightly less clunky than that of the built-in package (which was the OP's only complaint anyway).

Answer (score 1):

For the specific example you give, you *might* be able to improvise something using Guava's splitter:

```
for (String number : Splitter.onPattern("[^\d]+").split(input)) {
    // Do something with the number
}
```

or more specifically, if you had input like

```
SO question #1234, SO Question #3456, SO Question #5678
```

you might do

```
for (String number : Splitter.onPattern("(, )? SO Question #").split(input)) {
    // Do something
}
```

It's a bit hacky, but in specific cases it may do what you're after.